# WiFi interface configured as AP is down after system restart

Tags: ubuntu, networking, systemd-networkd, hostapd

I'm trying to setup my WiFi interface in AP mode using hostapd. However, after system restart startup hangs for about 2min on:

```
A start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured
```

It seems that WiFi interface is not getting UP and that is why systemd-networkd-wait-online.service hangs. It does not if I set WiFi interface as ignored in systemd-networkd-wait-online.service, but this does not solve the general problem.

After system startup I see this output after I execute `ip addr` command:

```
3: wlxc04a0010118a: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:4a:00:10:11:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

As I expected interface is DOWN.

`sudo ip link set wlxc04a0010118a up` does not change interface status. To bring it UP and fix my issue I have to execute `systemctl restart hostapd.service`

Then `ip addr` command returns:

```
3: wlxc04a0010118a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:4a:00:10:11:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.24.1.1/24 brd 172.24.1.255 scope global wlxc04a0010118a
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I would like to fix that and have WiFi AP configured after system startup without this manual step as other services rely on this interface and eventualy have to be also started manualy when interface is up. I tried many things but still cannot solve this. I would appreciate your help.

My `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
interface=wlxc04a0010118a
# Use the nl80211 driver with the brcmfmac driver
driver=nl80211
ssid=Wifinetwork
hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
# Enable 40MHz channels with 20ns guard interval
#ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=Wifipassword
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Interface configuration: `/lib/systemd/network/80-wifi-ap.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=wlxc04a0010118a

[Network]
Address=172.24.1.1/24
DHCPServer=no
IPForward=ipv4
IPMasquerade=no
```

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
interface=wlxc04a0010118a      # Use interface wlan0  
listen-address=172.24.1.1  # Explicitly specify the address to listen on  
bind-dynamic      # Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending things elsewhere  
server=8.8.8.8       # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS  
domain-needed        # Don't forward short names  
bogus-priv           # Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.  
dhcp-option=6,172.24.1.1,192.168.1.1
domain=domain1
dhcp-range=172.24.1.50,172.24.1.150,12h
```

Result of `systemctl status hostapd.service` before hostapd restart:

```
● hostapd.service - Hostapd IEEE 802.11 Access Point
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-11-10 16:42:02 UTC; 4min 48s ago
    Process: 780 ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip link set wlxc04a0010118a up (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 794 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf -P /var/run/hostapd.pid (code=exited, sta>
   Main PID: 966 (hostapd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4596)
     Memory: 2.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
             └─966 /usr/sbin/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf -P /var/run/hostapd.pid

Nov 10 16:41:58 domain1 systemd[1]: Starting Hostapd IEEE 802.11 Access Point...
Nov 10 16:41:58 domain1 hostapd[794]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Nov 10 16:42:00 domain1 hostapd[794]: Using interface wlxc04a0010118a with hwaddr c0:4a:00:10:11:8a and ssid ">
Nov 10 16:42:02 domain1 hostapd[794]: wlxc04a0010118a: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
Nov 10 16:42:02 domain1 hostapd[794]: wlxc04a0010118a: AP-ENABLED
Nov 10 16:42:02 domain1 systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Can't open PID file /run/hostapd.pid (yet?) after start: >
Nov 10 16:42:02 domain1 systemd[1]: Started Hostapd IEEE 802.11 Access Point.
```

Result of `systemctl status hostapd.service` after hostapd restart:

```
 hostapd.service - Hostapd IEEE 802.11 Access Point
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-11-10 17:32:36 UTC; 6min ago
    Process: 1499 ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip link set wlxc04a0010118a up (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1514 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf -P /var/run/hostapd.pid (code=exited, s>
   Main PID: 1522 (hostapd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4596)
     Memory: 816.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
             └─1522 /usr/sbin/hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf -P /var/run/hostapd.pid

Nov 10 17:32:30 domain1 systemd[1]: Stopping Hostapd IEEE 802.11 Access Point...
Nov 10 17:32:30 domain1 systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Succeeded.
Nov 10 17:32:30 domain1 systemd[1]: Stopped Hostapd IEEE 802.11 Access Point.
Nov 10 17:32:30 domain1 systemd[1]: Starting Hostapd IEEE 802.11 Access Point...
Nov 10 17:32:30 domain1 hostapd[1514]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Nov 10 17:32:34 domain1 hostapd[1514]: Using interface wlxc04a0010118a with hwaddr c0:4a:00:10:11:8a and ssid>
Nov 10 17:32:36 domain1 hostapd[1514]: wlxc04a0010118a: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
Nov 10 17:32:36 domain1 hostapd[1514]: wlxc04a0010118a: AP-ENABLED
Nov 10 17:32:36 domain1 systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Can't open PID file /run/hostapd.pid (yet?) after start:>
Nov 10 17:32:36 domain1 systemd[1]: Started Hostapd IEEE 802.11 Access Point.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I have installed XFCE desktop environment NetworkManager has been also installed. It looks that it somehow breaks my configuration and my wifi interface stays down. To avoid that I had to make this file:
`/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/unmanaged.conf` with this content:

```
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlxc04a0010118a
```

Now NetworkManager does not manage this interface. However, system still hangs during boot on:

```
A start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured
```

To avoid that I had to add:

```
[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no
```

to `/lib/systemd/network/80-wifi-ap.network` file.
Now system starts without this pause and wifi AP works as expected.
Still I am not sure why I have to add this `RequiredForOnline=no`. It looks that wifi interface somehow cannot be set UP at this stage of boot proces while probably it is set UP soon after that because in the end interface works well.